# How to generate html / pdf reports from a function within an R package

Tags: r, report, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to include a function in my R package that generates an html/pdf report, given some input data.

For example, let’s imagine the following function:

```
#' @title Nice Report
#' @description It generates a nice summary report
#' @param x data.frame with column `column_whatever`
#' @param y data frame with column `column_whatever`
#' @param outputFormat Output format: either `pdf`(default) or `html` 
#' @return Either html/pdf summary report
#' @keywords QC, report
#' @examples
#' render_a_nice_report(x = data_example1, y = data_example2)
#' @export
render_a_nice_report <- function(x, 
                                 y, 
                                 outputFormat = "pdf"){

    # do some stuff with x and y
    z <- merge(x, y, by=(column_whatever))

    # Nicely print the data frame:

    #' ### Head of table resulting from merging x and y

    knitr::kable(head(z))

    #' ### Title 1: Distribution of variable 1

    plot1 <- ggplot(z) + geom_density(aes(v1))

    print(plot1)

    #' Some description of the plot above

    # Do something else to z

    k <- mypackage::do_whatever(z)

    #' ### Title 2: Histogram of Variable Var2

    plot2 <- ggplot(k) + geom_histogram(aes(var2))

# and finish rendering the report
}
```

Is something like this even possible to do within a function?

If not, how can I accomplish something similar from a function within my package? using an Rmd template? but how would it work? would you be able to please provide an example of an existing R Package with a function doing something like this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Here's an example of a package that includes a variety of visualization / reporting functions: https://boxuancui.github.io/DataExplorer/

Comment: Wow! It's not only what I was looking for, the package itself is awesome! thanks a lot!